# Python: make list a json text but the list is invalid in this way

Tags: python

I'm trying to make json text from list.

**How I tried:**

```
data = ["id": "1", "title": "2", "data": "3"]
```

How I want it to be after json encoding:

```
{"id":"1","title":"2","data":"2"}
```

I'm trying to make the list for json... The problem is that the list is malfunctioning in this way

Comment: your list isn't even a valid list..whats the actual data look like that you're starting with

Comment: yep. its invalid

Comment: If you really want the json you show, you must start with a dict.

Comment: although very unclear...it looks as if you have some keys and values  (potentially in separate lists?) that can zip'd into a dict then be used by the json pkg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use list in this case

You need to use {key:value} like datatype in python you can use Dictionary Like:

```
import json

# some JSON:
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y)
```

It will done by using json library in python

For more information read docs and check https://realpython.com/python-json/

Comment: I was referring to how to make the list for json... The problem is that the list is not correct in this way

Comment: @redalert you must use {key:value} data type for example Dictionary

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, but how do you do it?

Comment: x={} for define dictionary check https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: so the solution to "make list a json text" is to make json text a dict?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `json.dumps`. For example -

```py
import json

list = ['a','b','c']
json_str = json.dumps(list)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here how pass object to json

```
import json

# a Python object (dict):
x = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "city": "New York"
}

# convert into JSON:
y = json.dumps(x)

# the result is a JSON string:
print(y)

#{"name": "John", "age": 30, "city": "New York"}
```

other convertions to json in python:

```
import json

print(json.dumps({"name": "John", "age": 30}))
print(json.dumps(["apple", "bananas"]))
print(json.dumps(("apple", "bananas")))
print(json.dumps("hello"))
print(json.dumps(42))
print(json.dumps(31.76))
print(json.dumps(True))
print(json.dumps(False))
print(json.dumps(None))
```

see it: 
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp
https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: I was referring to how to make the list for json... The problem is that the list is not correct in this way